# Does GDPR apply when PII is already publicly available?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, gdpr, european-union, data-protection-act

Pretend there is a website, it might be free to access, or be a paid per search service, where the users get access to summarised information on the people that they search for.

All of the information this website displays has been taken from public sources, such as news papers, personal profiles on company websites, LinkedIn, Facebook, other websites etc... Nothing has been copied from these sources, aside from the person's full name and position (such as secretary).

The people have never consented to having their data published onto this website, it was mined manually by employees.

Would the people be allowed to request their data be removed? I am interested in how GDPR or the Data Protection Act would apply when this information is already publicly available.

Comment: Data being public and data being in the public domain is not at all the same thing.

Comment: In those countries the GDPR was modelled after, even decades ago in the day of publicly available printed telephone books, "scraping" that data and using it was subject to deletion requests from the subject(s).

Comment: @EikePierstorff since the question doesn't mention copyright, I assume OP means the former and have edited the title accordingly

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The site would combine the data in novel ways, which is *processing* the data. Processing personal data which is publicly available is still processing personal data.

You would have to take GDPR into account. That does not mean the processing is forbidden, but you need a legal basis for doing it. In many ways, having the informed consent is the easiest legal basis, but there are others. The data subject would have the right to demand information about the data you hold, and to demand the correction of wrong data. There is not *necessarily* a right to demand deletion, but if consent is withdrawn and you have *no other* basis for data processing, you have to delete.

Note also that the consent basis would mean you have to *actively* contact the people whose consent you seek before the processing starts, and document how you do it. That makes pay-per-request models difficult.

But consider that the news media can process *some* data about *some* people without the consent of the subjects of their activities. They just need to balance privacy and other legitimate interests all the time.

Comment: The typical legal basis in this context would be a "legitimate interest", not consent. But LI requires performing a balancing test that takes into account the data subjects' reasonable expectations. Processing for journalistic purposes may benefit from an Art 85 GDPR exception, but that depends entirely on national laws.

Comment: @amon, the site could probably generate and post bios of sports stars or cabinet officials. But not bios of average guys.

Comment: Would it make any difference if this was information obtained from court transcripts - once again just focusing on full name, and title of the person?

Comment: @user5623335, it would make a difference, but how much of a difference depends on countless details, including the country you are operating in/from. Even convicted criminals have *some* right to privacy.

Comment: @user5623335 Careful when processing data about trials: Art 10 GDPR *forbids* processing that relates to criminal convictions, except as explicitly authorized by some other law.

Comment: If I never got consent, and they asked me to take it down, could I refuse by saying I got your name and title which is available for free publicly online? I am also refusing to take it down as I have a good reason - I am getting paid by my users.

Comment: @user5623335, not that simple. You will need to prepare formal documents, describing exactly which data you want to retain and on what legal basis, and why you think it applies. With consent, that is **relatively easy**. "They gave informed consent, so I do it." Still necessary to check that it is appropriate data use, or that the TOM are enough. Without consent, it is **harder**. You would have to explain why your interests in exploiting their data outweighs their interest in privacy. **If this is an idea for a startup company, your business plan needs to include hiring specialist lawyers.**

Comment: (Contd.) Any data you keep under GDPR rules has to come with a description of the purpose of the data processing, and you may use it only for that purpose. Generally speaking, the purposes which allow you to keep data without consent are unlikely to allow the publication of that data. For instance, a company must keep their invoices with the billing address of their customers, even if those customers demand data deletion. But those invoices may **only** be used for tax and accounting, not for marketing.

Comment: There is a qualified right to erasure aka right to be forgotten. Google v CNIL is an example of a case that seems to match the circumstances described by the question.